# Delete timezone and time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem. I have a table like this (example data):

| value | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 22.12 | 2023-01-18T08:00:35.000Z |
| 22.18 | 2023-01-18T09:13:12.000Z |
| 22.15 | 2023-01-18T09:16:12.000Z |
| 22.17 | 2023-01-18T09:49:35.000Z |
| 16.12 | 2023-01-25T10:15:05.000Z |
| 26.18 | 2023-01-25T10:40:05.000Z |
| 25.52 | 2023-01-25T10:55:05.000Z |
| 19.88 | 2023-01-26T11:40:05.000Z |
| 16.12 | 2023-01-16T12:40:05.000Z |

I'am getting an average of values and I'am grouping it by date. I use:

```
select cast(timestamp as date) as dt, AVG(value) as avg_val
from tbl_name
group by cast(timestamp as date);
```

And my result looks like this:

```
22.01384610396165   2023-01-18T23:00:00.000Z
```

Is it possible to get only data without time and timezone?

Comment: It does help if your Results actually looked like they came from the query :) `2023-01-18T23:00:00.000Z    22.01384610396165`

Comment: *I have a table like this (example data)* Shown values for `timestamp` column are **NOT** MySQL timestamp values. *And my result looks like this* The same. Finally: this is your client issue. Recommendation: cast the expression in your query to CHAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get only the date (without time or timezone) from the timestamp. You can use the DATE() function in your query to convert the timestamp to a date. The syntax would be:

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS dt
, AVG(value) AS avg_val 
FROM tbl_name 
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp);
```

This will return the result as:

```
22.01384610396165   2023-01-18
```

Comment: Well actually it will return `2023-01-18    22.01384610396165` :) :)

Comment: True. I just copied the OP's result

Comment: Sorry, I am having a pedantic day :)

Comment: It was client issue. I am working with Node.js. I just used `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, "%e-%m-%Y") as dt` and it works! :D